# Add CheckBox as Bullet inside RichTextBox

Tags: wpf

I was wondering if it was possible to create a list that has check boxes in place of bullets.

I want to create a lengthy list of questions inside RichTextBox and would like it to automatically place a small check box prior to each question. Much like it would place a bullet after each time I press 'enter'. I don't see a check box as an option in the list of bullets.

Answer (score 0):

WPF RichTextBox doesn't support checkbox as bullet. For your requirement you need to add check box as InlineUIContainer in RichTextBox.[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) is sample to play with flowdocument

Comment: the link seems to be broken.